# How to hide PPT presentation using com/ironPython

Tags: ironpython, powerpoint

When I try to set the property: `PowerPoint.ApplicationClass().Visible = False`

I get the following error message:

```
"Invalid request.  Hiding the application window is not allowed."
```

I found this [old thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31255287/unable-to-suppress-ppt-window.aspx) at eggheadcafe. So I modified my code according like such:

```
com_ppt = self.com_app.Presentations.Open(filename, WithWindow = False)
```

However, this only hides the PRESENTATION but still opens an APPLICATION WINDOW. So, basically, PPT opens but there's no presentation inside of it. Any help on this mystery would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what I've come up with. Seems to be working so far:

```
if self.isVisible:
    self.com_app.Visible = self.isVisible
com_ppt = self.com_app.Presentations.Open(filename, WithWindow = isVisible)
```

As far as I can tell, you can only set "Visible" equal to true. If you try to set it to False, it chokes. However, if you want to hide the window, you cannot set Visible to true and then set withWindow to false. It seems there is a third state for Visible (say, "undefined" or "default") which visible must be in in order to set WithWindow to False AND have the ppt application remain closed.

Answer (score 0):

WithWindow has to be msoFalse:

```
WithWindow: Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you have to leave `Application.Visible` property with it's default value:

```
var application = new Application();
var document = application.Presentations.Open(fileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
    WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

If you explicitly set `Application.Visible` property to `MsoTriState.msoFalse` you will get "Hiding the application window is not allowed" error.